# mysql lookup match

Tags: mysql

I have a database column like this:

```
id
50
55
56
62
63
64
65
68
70
72
80

etc...
```

I want to iterate through the id column with the following formula to find if the result of the formula is an id number in the same column. I want to compute all the possible combinations of the set of basically 3 records in the id column.

First loop:
Does ((second_id_number - first_id_number) * variable decimal) + second_id_number equal a number in the id column?

Per the formula, the first loop is
(55-50)*2.00(as an example of variable decimal) + 55 = 65. 65 is in the list => 65 is tagged with the 2 records which equal it

Second loop:
Does ((third_id_number - first_id_number) * variable decimal) + second_id_number equal a number in the id column?
(56-50)*2.00(as an example of variable decimal) + 56 = 78. 78 is not in the list => 78 is not tagged

Third loop:
Does ((fourth_id_number - first_id_number) * variable decimal) + second_id_number equal a number in the id column?

etc...

I want the results to show all the tagged records. A tagged record is the set of the 3 records where the third record is the result from the formula.

Anyone got any ideas? Is it possible in mysql?

Thank you

Comment: Could you please provide what the desired output should look like from your sample data?

Comment: In the second loop you replaced `second_id_number` with 56 except that's the third_id and not the second. Also what does "etc...? mean? Does this mean you go on until there's no more records?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your requirements properly, it sounds like you'd want to use a self-join on the table, e.g.

```
SELECT ...
FROM yourtable AS parent
LEFT JOIN yourtable AS child ON
    FLOOR((parent.second_id_number - parent.first_id_number) * variable) + parent.second_id) = child.id
```

Comment: I think its more complicated than that. The OP replaced `(second_id_number - first_id_number)` with `(55-50)` indicating that second_id_number is row after the first row.

Comment: Marc: Thanks for your answer. Iam not a programmer. Please indicate how you write out: second_id_number,first_id_number so I can see the loop. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially carry something like this forward, which satisfies your first "loop"

```
select a.id as first_id_number
    , b.id as second_id_number
    , ((b.id - a.id) * 2) + b.id as third_id_number
from my_table as a
    join my_table as b on a.id = (select max(id) from my_table where id < b.id)
where ((b.id - a.id) * 2) + b.id in (select id from my_table)
```

According to your description and test data, this would show 65 as "tagged" with first_id_number 50 and 62.

Warning: done on SQL Server using what I *think* is fairly standard syntax.  I would understand if some would rather phrase this as a cross join with the `select max...` bit in the where clause rather than in the join predicate.

Comment: You can use [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c0fb3/2) if you don't have MySQL installed

Comment: Thanks, Conrad. I have used that before when told that my code doesn't work!

Comment: Tim: Thanks for your answer. I don't see how the iterations are done in your code.

Comment: how would I use a counter to calculate the number of itertions/loops the query is doing? thanks